# Which index is used to answer aggregates when we have several indexes?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a table which is partitioned on daily basis, each partition has certainly a primary key, and several other indexes on columns which are not null. If I get the query plane for the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM parent_table;
```

I can see different indexes are used, sometimes the primary key index is used and some times others. How postgres is able to decide which index to use. Note that, my table is not clustered and never clustered before. Also, the primary key is serial.

What are the catalog / statistics tables which are used to make this decision.

Comment: Perhaps Postgres finds that the different indexes all have the same cost, so the one that is chosen is arbitrary.

Comment: May be, but I think,  there should be several factors, for example, the index size may be one of these factors.

Comment: Voted to move to dba.stackexchange, because this is really about the internals of PostgreSQL

Comment: An important factor may be which index is loaded to buffers.

Comment: I do not mind moving the question to dba, I am asking this, because after upgrading to PostgreSQL 9.6 parallel seq scan is used to evaluate the query above and it is not optimal as using index only scan. So, i would like to know more about the calculation. Note that, I often do cold testing because the server load is similar to DWH with lots of inserts and  few aggregate queries.

Comment: @Adam Whether IoS is used or not depends on several factors and it's rather dynamic and will change during normal daily use.